# What is the PHP sentence needed to add this function?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I run a PHP code that collects the data inputed by the user from a web-based form (CF7 plugin) and then export it to a XML file format.

In this form the user can fill in more than one type of course. For example: Engineering, Marketing, Medicine...

I´m looking for a sentence to add a function into my code that only "create" the attribute`s data (block of fields) when needed, that is, when the user fill in the info for more than 1 course instead of have it previously set and left in blank.

It´s because I cant predict how many courses the user can fill in,,,and I cant not just pre-create several block of fields "waiting" for the user´s input that may not occur. I can´t leave it blank. Need to be created as needed.

**My actual piece of code (2 block of field):**

```
$xmlSigam = $domDocument->createElement('SigaFiles');
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlSigam);  
$xmlSigam->setAttribute("Text", "SQM");  

$xml_dados = $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('Dados'));   
$xmlSigam->appendChild($xml_dados);

$attribute = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$attribute->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['code']));
$attribute->setAttribute('domainname', 'Code');

$attribute = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$attribute->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['course']));
$attribute->setAttribute('domainname', 'Course');

$attribute = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$attribute->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['description']));
$attribute->setAttribute('domainname', 'Description');

$xml_dadosmb = $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('Dados')); 
$xmlSigam->appendChild($xml_dadosmb);

$attributemb = $xml_dadosmb->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$attributemb->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['codemb']));
$attributemb->setAttribute('domainname', 'Code');

$attributemb = $xml_dadosmb->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$attributemb->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['coursemb']));
$attributemb->setAttribute('domainname', 'Course');

$attributemb = $xml_dadosmb->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
$attributemb->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($posted_data['descriptionmb']));
$attributemb->setAttribute('domainname', 'Description');
```

**Current XML File Format Output: (in case the user just fill in 1 block of field)**

```
<SigaFiles Text="SQM">
  <Data>
    <attribute domainname="Code">00001</attribute>
    <attribute domainname="Course">ENGINEERING</attribute>
    <attribute domainname="Description">COMPUTER ENGINEERING</attribute>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <attribute domainname="Code"></attribute>
    <attribute domainname="Course"></attribute>
    <attribute domainname="Description"></attribute>
  </Data>
</SigaFiles>
```

Comment: any clue for this ?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "the user can **fill in** more than one type of course". Is this coming from a multiselect field?

Comment: Temporarily add `print_r($_POST); exit();` to the top of your php file and show the results in your question.  It's problematic to answer your question not knowing the POST variables.

Comment: @Jamie_D no, it's coming from an already set available fields. Those information like "engineering" etc are written by the user.

Comment: You really should have a multiselect field in your html form that that is populated with available courses  that the user can select, instead of typing in a standard text field. that way you always know what format the course data is in.  Please provide an example of your HTML form (the relevant part if the form is too long)

Comment: @Jamie_D I am willing to use a "Switch statement" as a control structure. Do you believe it would work?  'switch (n) { case: condition  ...brake; }'

Comment: I will share with you how the form is set (the relevant part)

Comment: I added an answer for you to illustrate my comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a multiselect field in your form

```
<select  name="courses[]" id="countries" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="0001">Engineering</option>
  <option value="0002">History</option>
  <option value="0003">Computer Science</option>
  <option value="0004">Philosphy</option>
</select>
```

And in your post php block:

```
$xmlSigam = $domDocument->createElement('SigaFiles');
$xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlSigam);  
$xmlSigam->setAttribute("Text", "SQM");  

$xml_dados = $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('Dados'));   
$xmlSigam->appendChild($xml_dados);

$course_array = $_POST['courses'];
foreach($courses as $courseCode => $course)
{
  $attribute = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
  $attribute->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($courseCode));
  $attribute->setAttribute('domainname', 'Code');

  $attribute = $xml_dados->appendChild($domDocument->createElement('attribute'));
  $attribute->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode($course));
  $attribute->setAttribute('domainname', 'Course');
}
```